# Объясните алгоритм нахождения простых делителей числа

Tags: python, алгоритм

Можете объяснить алгоритм данного кода. Данный код находит простые делители числа.

```
def simpleDividers(n):
   answer = []
   d = 2
   while d * d <= n:
       if n % d == 0:
           answer.append(d)
           n //= d
       else:
           d += 1
   if n > 1:
       answer.append(n)
   return answer
```

Comment: А что тут говорить... не самый эффективный способ разложения числа на простые множители...

Answer (score 1):

```
def simpleDividers(n):
   answer = [] # пустой список
   d = 2 # начальное значение проверяемого делителя
   while d * d <= n: # проверяем делители до корня из n
       if n % d == 0: # если остаток от деления = 0
           answer.append(d) # то добавляем в ответ
           n //= d # делим n на d
       else:
           d += 1 # проверяем следующий делитель
   if n > 1: # если в итоге n > 1
       answer.append(n) # добавляем в ответ ещё этот n
   return answer # возвращаем
```

Comment: А как именно действует цикл while? Непонятно почему именно такой алглоритмм

Comment: @Krasava666777 что именно непонятно? Каждая строчка же прокомментирована. Вот одно из многих описаний алгоритма https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Перебор_делителей